# Path error when trying to use appletviewer jGRASP

Tags: java, applet, jgrasp, appletviewer

Whenever I attempt to run my code I am met with an error saying my path is wrong. This is the message I receive.

> ----jGRASP exec: appletviewer jgrasphta.html
>   ----jGRASP wedge error: command "appletviewer" not found.
>   ----   This command must be in the current Working directory
>   ----   or on the current PATH to use this function.
>   ----   working directory is "C:\Users\Carson\Desktop\Java".
>   ----   PATH is ";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Carson\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps".
>   ----jGRASP: operation complete.

The problem is not that I don't have jdk isntalled. I have reinstalled jdk 12 multiple times as well as jGRASP with no results. I have all over the internet for a solution and couldn't find one.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Java0408 extends Applet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Expo.drawLine(g,100,100,900,550);
        Expo.drawLine(g,100,550,900,100);
        Expo.drawLine(g,100,325,900,325);
        Expo.drawLine(g,500,100,500,550);
    }
}
```

It's supposed to make a graphic in applet but it doesn't even open it up. I only get the error saying the path is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"reinstalled jdk 12 multiple times"* Java 12? AFAIU, support for applets was removed in Java 9. But applets are a dead technology in any case. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).